# Selecting table rows from one table where value of table column in another table is x

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to SELECT rows from a table where it has got a foreign key on second table and the key from the second table is used in a third table as foreign key. How can I retrieve the rows from the first table where on the third table doesn't have the key from the second table which this particular key's row has got the first tables' row's primary key as foreign key and also on the third table it hasn't got the foreign key of the fourth table.

I tried using inner join but it only works with SELECTING rows where it has got a specify value rather than not having this specify value.

Please help me

Faculty table

```
FaculID | FaculName | FaculLocation |
```

Course table

```
CourseID | CourseName | CourseDescription
```

FacultyCourse table

```
fcID | CourseID | FaculID
```

Registeration table

```
RegID | fcID | stuID
```

Student table

```
stuID | stuName | stuAge | stuAddress
```

so basically what i want to do now is get all bid where the e table hasn't got uid and did(which has got a bid foreign key).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: As previously stated you need to provide more information, you could start by looking at a `LEFT JOIN` and maybe adding a `WHERE columnName IS NULL` to the conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi there I have edited the table list... and coloured them on bold those identifier I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

(change table and column names as appropriate)

updated based on example layout

```
select *
  from faculty
 where faculid not in (select faculty.FaculID
                         from faculty
                         join facultycourse 
                           on faculty.FaculID = FacultyCourse.FaculID
                         join registration
                           on registration.fcid = FacultyCourse.fcid
                        where registration.stuid = 'XYZ');
```

Comment: Hello there thank you for your input basically what I am trying to do is something like this e.g. there is a student and he registered to many faculty but I want to get all faculty that he is not registered into. And in a faculty there is a many courses so he can be registered into any to be considered as in a specific faculty.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem but I need to know the table names (ex. students, courses, faculty, etc.) the columns on each table, and the relationships between them. In this query I am selecting all rows from the table that you called "b table" where the bid column is not reflected by any uid values on the "u table" (using joins between b and d, d and e, and e and u, to get there). It might help if you elaborate with some example data on each table, including the actual column names.

Comment: Hello there sorry about the confusion I have just edited the table I don't know if there is adequate information but basically a faculty can run multiple courses so I have a faculcourse table....new faculty can be made then courses can be entered....there are instances a student might need to do the same course because of the faculty they join. Hence I am trying to search for the faculty the student isn't registered to yet.

Comment: If I use outer join and inner join it returns with a Where claus stating stuid = "1"....it returns all the faculty the student is entered too but i want to do the opposite to that

Comment: @urhydy I just edited my answer based on your table structure and explanation. Let me know how that works out. This should return all faculty who do not teach ANY classes to which the specified student is registered.

Comment: Thank you could you please explain to me what f. is and c and r are you representing faculty , course , and registration?

Comment: f is just an alias for your faculty table, c is a an alias for your facultycourse table, r is an alias for your registration table. If you don't want to use aliases you can leave them out and in their place use the whole table name each time.

Comment: Wow thank you learnt something....had to change within the brackets but now its working great!!! Appreciate all your help and time!!!!

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed the answer a bit to match the columns and tables so can be referenced to again...

Answer (score 3):

Try to use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b on a.keya = b.keybjoina
LEFT OUTER JOIN c on b.keybjoina = c.keycjoinb
WHERE c.keycjoinb IS NULL
```